# How can i get Apache to log who started/stopped it?

Tags: logging, apache2

I need Apache2.2 to log the username of anyone who tries to start or stop it. How do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

This could be achived by sudo, not allowing users to log in as root directly and allow them only specific action, and each action can be logged.